# Data Structure Issue

Tags: powerbi

I have an issue where I have a Table that contains employees' names and their team structure from staff all the way to supervisor4. For example, the hierarchy goes from Jane > Mary > John > Jim > Dwight. The problem I have is that some teams' structures don't go all the way to supervisor4 so the leftover columns are left with NULL, for example, Jerry > Melissa > NULL > NULL.

I guess my question is - is there any other data structure format I can use to avoid these NULLS? I'm trying to load this into PowerBI and having the NULLs show isn't the prettiest. See below for my table.

I have already tried displaying it in a table format and tree format (with plus signs to drill down the tree) but the table shows NULLs and the tree shows blank. I don't want it to show nulls or blanks. I've tried a sunburst chart but my real data set is too big for it. Any ideas honestly would help.

```
Staff   Supervisor  Supervisor2 Supervisor3      Supervisor4
Jane    Mary            John            Jim             Dwight
Jerry   Melissa         NULL            NULL            NULL
Kevin   Paul            lonny           NULL            NULL
Mike    Pauline         Adrien          Adrien          Larry
Chris   Amy             Adam            Erin            NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with this kind of data, but I've never seen it in that format - what happens when Jane starts supervising and there is a Supervisor5 column needed.

I'd probably try putting the data back into a true hierarchical format and work that way.

```
EmployeeID SupervisorID
```

Then use a visualization that is meant for this such as this: [Hierarchy Chart by Akvelon](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381333?tab=Overview)

Or you could try using a CTE to produce a resultant table with hierarchy levels & include some organizational data such as UNIT, etc, put some filters on the data.
[Hierarchy Example](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/)